# How to close one ExpandablePanel when the other opens?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use expandable - ExpandablePanel. And the problem is how to close first ExpandablePanel when the second opens? I try with controller.value but I can't find something like actions or onChange. How to do this?

```
ExpandablePanel(
                controller: categoryController,
                iconPlacement: ExpandablePanelIconPlacement.right,
                header: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Category',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 21.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    )),
                expanded: Container(
                  child: Icon(Icons.close)),
                tapHeaderToExpand: true,
                hasIcon: true,
              ),
ExpandablePanel(
                controller: subCategoryController,
                iconPlacement: ExpandablePanelIconPlacement.right,
                header: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'SubCategory',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 21.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    )),
                expanded: Container(
                  child: Icon(Icons.close)),
                tapHeaderToExpand: true,
                hasIcon: true,
              ),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably the easiest solution.

```
categoryController.addListener((){
      if(categoryController.value)sexController.value=false;
    });
    sexController.addListener((){
      if(sexController.value)categoryController.value=false;
    });
```

Comment: Yup this is easier :)

Comment: where I can add this code?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using **[Expandable](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable)** package for flutter?

If yes, then that package doesn't have this functionality.

[read this](https://github.com/aryzhov/flutter-expandable/issues/8)

However you can do this by making some custom code yourself.

I tried it and able to do this by some custom hack.

```
class _ExpandableDemoState extends State<ExpandableDemo> {
  ExpandableController categoryController, subCategoryController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    categoryController = ExpandableController(initialExpanded: false);
    subCategoryController = ExpandableController(initialExpanded: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                _toggleExpandables(0);
              },
              child: ExpandablePanel(
                controller: categoryController,
                iconPlacement: ExpandablePanelIconPlacement.right,
                header: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Category',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    )),
                expanded: Container(child: Icon(Icons.close)),
                tapHeaderToExpand: false,
                hasIcon: true,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
              onTap: (){
                _toggleExpandables(1);
              },
              child: ExpandablePanel(
                controller: subCategoryController,
                iconPlacement: ExpandablePanelIconPlacement.right,
                header: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'SubCategory',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    )),
                expanded: Container(child: Icon(Icons.close)),
                tapHeaderToExpand: false,
                hasIcon: true,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _toggleExpandables(int index){
    setState(() {
     categoryController.value = false;
    subCategoryController.value = false;

    _getController(index).value = true; 
    });
  }

  ExpandableController _getController(int index){
    switch(index){
      case 0:
        return categoryController;
      case 1:
        return subCategoryController;
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**- This code is not final & made in hurry. You can refactor this code for performance and as per your need.

Comment: Thanks buy this is easier. ```categoryController.addListener((){
      if(categoryController.value)sexController.value=false;
    });
    sexController.addListener((){
      if(sexController.value)categoryController.value=false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve this using `ExpansionPanelList.radio` with `ExpansionPanelRadio` [check it in the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList/ExpansionPanelList.radio.html)

```dart
Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList.radio(
      initialOpenPanelValue: 0,
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanelRadio>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanelRadio(
            value: item.id,
            headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(item.headerValue),
              );
            },
            body: ListTile(
                title: Text(item.expandedValue),
                subtitle: Text('To delete this panel, tap the trash can icon'),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _data.removeWhere((currentItem) => item == currentItem);
                  });
                }));
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve this you have to add this method after:

```
    tapHeaderToExpand: false,
```

make sure to don't use useInkWell.
the code is :

```
    _toggleExpandables(int index) {
setState(() {
  if (index == 0) {
    categoryController1.value = categoryController1.value ? false : true;
    categoryController2.value = false;
  } else {
    categoryController2.value = categoryController2.value ? false : true;
    categoryController1.value = false;
  }

  //  _getController(index)?.value = true;
});
```